# How to connect Devexpress scheduler with a custom data table

Tags: devexpress-windows-ui

```
DataSet1 ds1 = new DataSet1();

ds1.tblSchedul.Rows.Add(0, "t_test", "4/10/2013 11:30:00 AM", "0", "D", "", "", "", "4/10/2013 8:15:45 AM", "2", "sub", "0");
tblSchedulBindingSource.DataSource = ds1.tblSchedul;
```

But it is not working. Whats the possible solution ??

Answer (score 0):

```
   using System.Threading;
   using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
   using System.Data.Odbc;
   using DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls;
   using DevExpress.XtraEditors;

   namespace Project
  {
  public partial class frmSchedule : Form
  {

      DataSet scheduleDataset;
      SQLConnection scheduleConn;
      SQLDataAdapter scheduleAdapter;
         private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {            
                        schedulerControl1.Start = DateTime.Now;
                        scheduleDataset = new DataSet();
                        scheduleConn = objconnection.getConnection();// DatabaseConnection
                        scheduleConn.Open();               
                        fillData("SELECT * FROM table_name"); 
                }

         private void fillData(string query)
            {
                scheduleDataset = new DataSet();
                scheduleAdapter = new SQLDataAdapter(query, scheduleConn);
                scheduleAdapter.RowUpdated += new SQLRowUpdatedEventHandler(scheduleAdapter_RowUpdated);
                scheduleAdapter.Fill(scheduleDataset, "table_name");

                this.appointmentsBS.DataSource = scheduleDataset;
                this.appointmentsBS.DataMember = "table_name";
                this.appointmentsBS.Position = 0;

                                    this.schedulerStorage1.Appointments.DataSource = this.appointmentsBS;
                                    this.schedulerStorage1.Appointments.Mappings.field1= "Field1";         
                                    this.schedulerStorage1.Appointments.Mappings.Field2= "Field2";



                               AppointmentCustomFieldMapping IDD = new AppointmentCustomFieldMapping("IDD", "IDD");
                               schedulerStorage1.Appointments.CustomFieldMappings.Add(IDD);


                SQLCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SQLCommandBuilder(scheduleAdapter);
                scheduleAdapter.InsertCommand = cmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
                scheduleAdapter.DeleteCommand = cmdBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();
                scheduleAdapter.UpdateCommand = cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
            }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks For your reply, I don't want to use any database. Just simply a script and some data to show in schedulerControl.

Thanks.

Comment: I just edited the answer, you should use a schedulerStorage also creat a binding source appointmentsBS hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Appointments Mapping for the database tabel . 
first , load the database tabel in     DataTabel and use mapping method to maps the fields .

try looking at this code : [Devexpress Mapping](http://pastebin.com/Js4wzt2J)